# Suppose $n$ is a four digit number greater than $4100$ and less than $4900$. How many digits does $n^{4}$ have?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logarithms, contest-math

My solution approach :-
I was trying to solve this using Logarithm concept i.e. the number of digits in a positive integer $n$ written in base $10$ is $\lfloor{log_{10 }\text{ n}}\rfloor +1$. So ;
$\text{Let }n^4=N$
$\Rightarrow logN=4log\text{ n}$

But how can we get the value of $log\text{ n}$ as $4100<n<4900$? I am getting confused here ! Please help me on this !!!

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Hint: $4\log 4100\lt 4\log n\lt 4\log 4900$ i.e. $14.451135\ldots < \log n<14.760784\ldots$

Comment: @StinkingBishop : What if one can't calculate the value of log 4100 i.e if this question would have come up in the exam?

Comment: Then one should put that condition into the question. The answer could be quite different with "calculators allowed" vs. "calculators prohibited". Also, have you got the condition that you *must* use logarithms? (Or are you able to use anything else, like the answer you already got below?)

Comment: Hmmm...as this question came up while I was giving a mock exam for something and in that I had no calculator. Seems like this isn't the appropriate way to solve this question then. No there was no restriction to use only Log, i just used this method because I had read about this way.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: $4^4=256$ and $5^4=625$ each have three digits. So how many digits must $4100^4$ and $4900^4$ have? (You don't need logarithms at all.)

Comment: I think you mean $5^4=625$.